# C++ metaprogramming assign unique ID to tree structures

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, uniqueidentifier

I have an odd problem. I have a metaprogramming type defined like so:

```
template <int N, typename... Args>
struct mytype {
    ...
};
```

By default, I create them like this:

```
using type = mytype<-1, mytype<-1, mytype<-1, ...>>>;
```

or:

```
using type = mytype<-1, mytype<-1, ...>, mytype<-1, mytype<-1, ...>>>;
```

Later on, I need to recurse through the type and recursively set each number to a unique ID. The IDs need to be sequential and start at 0 for long technical reasons. For instance, if I had this:

```
mytype<-1
    mytype<-1, a, b>
>
```

I want it to become something like this:

```
mytype<0,
    mytype<1, a, b>
>
```

It doesn't matter the order for the numbers' assignment.

I don't quite know how to approach this problem and have tried several things that didn't get anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can it be `mytype<0, mytype<...>, mytype<...>>`? Or is the innermost `mytype` the only one with multiple types?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1404d3d38fc41fb6 for the simpler case. Allowing multiple `mytype`s on the same level will be more tricky.

Comment: @T.C. It can be that. I'll edit the question to show.

Comment: @T.C. BTW, I already tried that. It didn't work because of the fact that the nested can get so complex.

Comment: How about http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f659573a445048a?

Comment: So you're trying to create a map? Is there a reason you can't just use a map?

Comment: @JonathanMee Not necessarily. It's kind of complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is the same as @Brian's answer:

1. The metafunction must keep track of the values already used (or equivalently, the next available value) and the resulting type.
2. Since the handling of each type in the list is dependent on the previous type, simple pack expansion is not feasible, and you need to handle it using recursion.

The minor differences are that I didn't use a separate counter type, and that I do a preorder traversal rather than a postorder one. I also handled the concatenation differently.

```
// This is the base case, used only when T is not a mytype.
// N is the next index available to be used.
// The third argument is used to hold types that has been processed
// during the recursion.
template<class T, int N = 0, class = mytype<-1>> struct assign_IDs {
    using type = T; 
    static constexpr int next_index = N;
};

// When we are starting to process a mytype.
template<class T, class...Ts, int N, int M1, int M2>
struct assign_IDs<mytype<M1, T, Ts...>, N, mytype<M2>> {
    // Process the first type in the list.
    // The first available index is N+1 since we are using N.
    using T_assigned = assign_IDs<T, N + 1>;

    // recursively process the next type
    using next = assign_IDs<mytype<N, Ts...>, T_assigned::next_index, mytype<N, typename T_assigned::type>>;

    using type = typename next::type;
    static constexpr int next_index = next::next_index;
};

// When we are in the middle of processing a mytype. The difference
// is that we won't consume an index any more.
template<class T, class...Ts, class... Vs,  int N, int M1, int M2>
struct assign_IDs<mytype<M1, T, Ts...>, N, mytype<M2, Vs...>> {

    // now the handling of T can start at N.
    using T_assigned = assign_IDs<T, N>;

    using next = assign_IDs<mytype<M1, Ts...>, T_assigned::next_index, mytype<M2, Vs..., typename T_assigned::type>>;

    using type = typename next::type;
    static constexpr int next_index = next::next_index;
};

// end of recursion: all types have been processed.
// The resulting type is just the third template argument.
template<class... Vs, int N, int M1, int M2>
struct assign_IDs<mytype<M1>, N, mytype<M2, Vs...>> {
    using type = mytype<M2, Vs...>;
    static constexpr int next_index = N;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f659573a445048a).

[A postorder traversal](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8048bd77a5ebffd4) will actually be simpler to implement, because it takes one fewer partial specialization:

```
// same as before
template<class T, int N = 0, class = mytype<-1>> struct assign_IDs {
    using type = T; 
    static constexpr int next_index = N;
};

// can merge case #2 and #3 because now the handling is the same
// as the index isn't consumed until the end of the recursion
template<class T, class...Ts, class... Vs,  int N, int M1, int M2>
struct assign_IDs<mytype<M1, T, Ts...>, N, mytype<M2, Vs...>> {
    using T_assigned = assign_IDs<T, N>;
    using next = assign_IDs<mytype<M1, Ts...>, T_assigned::next_index, mytype<M2, Vs..., typename T_assigned::type>>;
    using type = typename next::type;
    static constexpr int next_index = next::next_index;
};

// end of recursion, consume an index for the current mytype that we are processing
template<class... Vs, int N, int M1, int M2>
struct assign_IDs<mytype<M1>, N, mytype<M2, Vs...>> {
    using type = mytype<N, Vs...>;
    static constexpr int next_index = N + 1;
};
```

OTOH, I liked having the numbers in increasing order when the type is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Basic ideas:

1. Template recursion over the variadic parameter pack in a `mytype`, that is, the metafunction should call itself with one fewer argument either before or after processing the first type in the list.
2. Use a type that keeps track of not only a result type but also the next value of the counter. You need to remember the new value of the counter after fully recursively traversing a subtree, because that's the starting value for the next subtree (or the current node). So your metafunction needs to return that as well.

Here's my solution, which assigns IDs in postorder (and is probably more complicated than it needs to be):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int placeholder, typename... Args>
struct mytype {};

using type = mytype<-1, mytype<-1, int, float>, mytype<-1, char, double>>;
using result = mytype<2, mytype<0, int, float>, mytype<1, char, double>>;

// This helper type is used to keep track of the next counter value
template <int c, typename T>
struct type_with_counter {
  static constexpr int counter = c;
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename T> struct assign_ids_helper;

// Base case: we have no mytype and no placeholders to assign, so just give
// back the original type and leave the counter alone.
template <int c, typename T>
struct assign_ids_helper<type_with_counter<c, T>> {
  typedef type_with_counter<c, T> result;
};

// Base case: we have a mytype with no children; assign the placeholder and
// increment the counter.
template <int c, int placeholder>
struct assign_ids_helper<type_with_counter<c, mytype<placeholder>>> {
  typedef type_with_counter<c+1, mytype<c>> result;
};

// Recursive case: one or more children.
template <int c, int placeholder, typename head, typename... tail>
struct assign_ids_helper<type_with_counter<c, mytype<placeholder, head, tail...>>> {
  // Recurse into the first type.
  typedef typename assign_ids_helper<type_with_counter<c, head>>::result head_result;
  // Now use the updated counter to recurse on the tail.
  typedef typename assign_ids_helper<type_with_counter<head_result::counter, mytype<placeholder, tail...>>>::result tail_result;
  // The new type will be given by inserting the head into the tail
  template <typename, typename> struct cons;
  template <int id, typename head_, typename... tail_>
  struct cons<head_, mytype<id, tail_...>> {
    typedef mytype<id, head_, tail_...> result;
  };
  typedef typename cons<typename head_result::type, typename tail_result::type>::result type;
  typedef type_with_counter<tail_result::counter, type> result;
};

template <typename T>
using assign_ids = typename assign_ids_helper<type_with_counter<0, T>>::result::type;

int main() {
  static_assert(std::is_same<assign_ids<type>, result>::value, "");
}
```

(link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d9507359e9ebc07)

@T.C. also posted a solution in the comments, which appears to be simpler.